# Changes not working after deploying

Tags: asp.net

I have made some changes to .cs file and copied the file into server where web application is hosted. But the changes I did are not reflecting. Please suggest a solution.

I tried copying .cs file alone also copied entire application files.

Did IISRESET and app pool recycle as well. But nothing works.

Comment: Is this webforms? MVC?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time when you're dealing with .cs files, you need to compile and copy the results of your build to the webserver.  A combination of the .aspx/.cshtml files and bin directory including the .dll files

Answer (score 0):

Here is a procedure that you can follow.

1. Create the `app_offline.htm` file on the root of your site, so the site will be off
2. Upload the updated files.

   - Now when you upload your files, if you have an Updated DLL, for your bin all is ok. You can even copy at least one dll on the bin, even if its not updated.
   - If you do not have that, update the `web.config` even with an empty line on the end, to give a signal to the site that needs some update.
3. Rename/remove the `app_offline.htm` from root and make the site online again